# Bash script to ping multiple hosts in staggered terminal windows

Tags: bash, ping

I want to:

1. open 5 terminal windows
2. use each terminal window to ping a distinct host on the network (continuously)

Currently I do this manually each time in order to find out what's going on in my terrible home network....Also, I wish to know if there's a good book for me to self learn bash scripting. it's impressive.

Appreciate all the help i can get in advance.

[image: currently this is what i do]

Comment: How about using `nmap` instead? There are also versions of ping that work with several destinations in parallel. Or in case your terminal is gnome-terminal, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135995/how-to-open-a-gnome-terminal-to-execute-a-command-with-gnome-terminal-constantl.

Comment: How about **not** posting images of text - you could have copied the text output quite easily.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397) (follow the link to understand why)

Comment: Why you need to open five different terminal from a script? How many packets the `ping` should send?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to do this via a script (assuming that you work with `gnome-terminal` and IPv4). Below I open a terminal window for each ping'ed IP address and stagger those windows by a quantity of pixels you can tweak. Each Gnome terminal window is identified with a title that contains the ping'ed IP:

Once you have created your script, e.g. `my_ping.sh`, make sure you make it executable, with:

```
$ chmod a+x my_ping.sh        # see manual page for `chmod' if needed.
```

**Version A**

```
$ cat my_ping.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash
ip_array=(8.8.8.8 
          8.8.4.4 
          192.168.1.1) # define array with as many IPs as needed
x0=50; y0=50    # top left corner pixel coordinates of 1st term-window to open
pix_offset=50   # pixel xy-offset for subsequently staggered PING windows

for ip in "${ip_array[@]}"; do
    sizeloc="80X24+$x0+$y0"
    gnome-terminal --window \
                   --geometry="$sizeloc" \
                   --title "PING $ip" \
                   -- \ping "$ip"
    x0=$((x0+pix_offset));y0=$((y0+pix_offset))
done
```

Usage: `$ my_ping.sh`

**Version B**

You might want to provide the list of IP addresses to ping as arguments to the script `my_ping.sh`.

```
$ cat my_ping.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash
x0=50; y0=50
pix_offset=50

# Include IP type-checking here if needed 
for ip in "$@"; do
    sizeloc="80X24+$x0+$y0"
    gnome-terminal --window \
                   --geometry="$sizeloc" \
                   --title "PING $ip" \
                   -- \ping "$ip"
    x0=$((x0+pix_offset)); y0=$((y0+pix_offset))
done
```

Usage: `$ my_ping.sh 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 192.168.1.1 [...]`

---

Ideally and at least in "Version B" you probably should make sure that the IP addresses are type-checked by the script. You would do this in the script before the `for` loop. HTH.